# use innerHTML to change dynamically created objects of a page

Tags: javascript, html

.Hi guys! is it possible to use `.innerHTML` to change my textbox named `text1` which is dynamically created using `.appendChild`? help please! TIA!

Comment: If you use `.innerHTML` of the textbox's parent element then yes - but that will effectively replace the entire textbox with whatever you specify. What about it do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is.

```
<body>

    <div id="test">
        <p>initial text</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

var myDiv = document.getElementById('test');
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "This is innerHtml";
myDiv.appendChild(p);
p.setAttribute('id', 'text1');


    </script>
</body>
```